# Simple way to do dynamic but square layout

Tags: android

I'm using a `GridView` to display a bunch of views which are essentially `LinearLayouts`. I want the `LinearLayouts` to all be square, but I also want them to be dynamically sized--that is, there are two columns and I want the `LinearLayouts` to stretch depending on the size of the screen but remain square. Is there a way to do this through the `xml` layout or do I have to set the heights and widths programmatically?

Answer (score 116):

A neat solution for square `GridView` items is to extend `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` and override `onMeasure` like so:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: This is using the measure spec rather than using setMeasuredDimension() so that is good. But it's not very flexible since it always takes the width.

Comment: As @DavidMerriman said above, if the view is wider than it is tall, this will cause the view to extend below the viewing area, cutting off part of the view.

Comment: This would be more flexible if it passed the value of Math.min(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) into both arguments of super.onMeasure()

Comment: This will work easily with activities but it won't work with an app widget.

Answer (score 85):

With the new [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) introduced in Android Studio 2.3, it is now quite easy to build responsive layouts.

In a parent ConstraintLayout, to make any of its children view/layout dynamically square, add this attribute

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
```

w is to specify width-wise constraints and 1:1 ratio ensures square layout.

Comment: Make sure to set "0dp" for layout width and height in child layout. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It also works for the view itself, I mean if you want a contrantLayout's child to be square, you can define the layout_constraintDimensionRatio attribute directly in the child view

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution; I've made if it helps  a complete gist of my code using your solution: https://gist.github.com/nadar71/006699e31ef7451813e6c97dacfbc5e2

Answer (score 45):

I've done this way:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int size;
    if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthSize > 0){
        size = widthSize;
    }
    else if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightSize > 0){
        size = heightSize;
    }
    else{
        size = widthSize < heightSize ? widthSize : heightSize;
    }

    int finalMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(finalMeasureSpec, finalMeasureSpec);
}
```

With this implementation, your layout will be square, assuming the lower size between width and height. And it can even be set with dynamic values, like using weight inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: the method "onMeasure" is to be overrided in a class that extend GridView ?

Comment: Tt's overriden in the class you want it to be square. For the case of the question, it's the LinearLayouts inside the GridView.

Comment: This one helped me fix some strange issues in using a square view in a StaggeredGridLayout. My more naive implementation was not good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

There's nothing in the xml that will let you link the width and height properties.  Probably the easiest thing to do is to subclass `LinearLayout` and override `onMeasure`

```
@Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

I've used this to create views that are always square before.  It should still work for a `LinearLayout`.

More info that will help doing this: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html

Comment: If this worked for you, could you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Well, I arrived at a solution that while similar, is a little different from this, and I couldn't get it work with onMeasure, so I'm not sure that this code snippet would have worked for me.

Comment: @Catherine hey Catherine, can you post your snippet? Maybe it'd be useful for others :-)

Comment: @MarekSebera In retrpospect, that probably would have been a good idea... but it's been a very long time and I'm no longer even working with that codebase!

Comment: Don't forgot to add : `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);` !

Comment: @deKajoo Using `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);` does give you a square, but it's always width x width. If the measurements given are wider than they are tall, you're going to have a problem. My solution uses the smaller of the two measurements, so that you always get the largest square that will fit within the given rectangle.

Comment: Without a call to `super.onMeasure()` child views won't be laid out properly.

Comment: Downvote for the ternary operator. Take the Math.min of the two values instead, I'd say.

Answer (score 9):

We can do it with a very simple way - just call `super.onMeasure()` twice.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int squareLen = Math.min(width, height);

    super.onMeasure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(squareLen, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(squareLen, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

By calling `super.onMeasure()` twice, this is less efficient in terms of the drawing process, but it is a simple way to fix layout issues that the other answers can cause.

Comment: instead of calling super.onMeasure twice, the second time you only need to call setMeasuredDimension(squareLen, squareLen);

Comment: Calling `super.onMeasure()` twice makes sure that the layout is done correctly given the new size of the view. Without this we need to trigger a layout in a different way or deal with incorrect layouts.

Answer (score 5):

It is as simple as:

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        if (widthMeasureSpec < heightMeasureSpec) 
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        else
            super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line in XML:

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

Comment: I wanted to post the same answer because it's better than app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1" as it always keeps ratio if you change configuration

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works for all layout parameters that can be set to view or viewgroup:

```
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthDesc = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightDesc = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = 0;
    if (widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
            && heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        size = DP(defaultSize); // Use your own default size, in our case
                                // it's 125dp
    } else if ((widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            && !(widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)) {
                    //Only one of the dimensions has been specified so we choose the dimension that has a value (in the case of unspecified, the value assigned is 0)
        size = width > height ? width : height;
    } else {
                    //In all other cases both dimensions have been specified so we choose the smaller of the two
        size = width > height ? height : width;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
```

Cheers

Comment: This answer has some interesting characteristics and is potentially more robust, but needs work and should construct measure specs which get passed to super.onMeasure() rather than setMeasuredDimension() as it would allow for a variety of super classes.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create a custom layout class that inherits from FrameLayout. Override the OnMeasure() method and put whatever control you want to be square inside that SquareFrameLayout.

This is how it's done in Xamarin.Android:

```
public class SquareFrameLayout : FrameLayout
{
    private const string _tag = "SquareFrameLayout";

    public SquareFrameLayout(Android.Content.Context context):base(context) {}
    public SquareFrameLayout(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer):base(javaReference, transfer) {}
    public SquareFrameLayout(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context, attrs) {}
    public SquareFrameLayout(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr):base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}
    public SquareFrameLayout(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes):base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {}

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        var widthMode = MeasureSpec.GetMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        var heightMode = MeasureSpec.GetMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int width, height;

        switch (widthMode)
        {
            case MeasureSpecMode.Exactly:
                width = widthSize;
                break;
            case MeasureSpecMode.AtMost:
                width = Math.Min(widthSize, heightSize);
                break;
            default:
                width = 100;
                break;
        }

        switch (heightMode)
        {
            case MeasureSpecMode.Exactly:
                height = heightSize;
                break;
            case MeasureSpecMode.AtMost:
                height = Math.Min(widthSize, heightSize);
                break;
            default:
                height = 100;
                break;
        }

        Log.Debug(_tag, $"OnMeasure({widthMeasureSpec}, {heightMeasureSpec}) => Width mode: {widthMode}, Width: {widthSize}/{width}, Height mode: {heightMode}, Height: {heightSize}/{height}");
        var size = Math.Min(width, height);
        var newMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        base.OnMeasure(newMeasureSpec, newMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

If you want a View (or any other control) to be square (and centered) just add it to your layout the following way:

```
<your.namespace.SquareFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/squareContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/squareContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</your.namespace.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SquareLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout), an **Android Library** which provides a wrapper class for different Layouts, rendering them Squared dimensioned without losing any core functionalities.

The **dimensions are calculated just before the Layout is rendered**, hence there is no re-rendering or anything as such to adjust once the View is obtained.

To use the Library, add this to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:squarelayout:0.0.3'
}
```

The one you require is [SquareLinearLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout).

Comment: Doesn't work for me on real device :( Rendering well on Android Studio preview, but is not working on device

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wants solution With Kotlin, here's what I did with `FrameLayout`.

```
package your.package.name

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.FrameLayout

class SquareLayout: FrameLayout {

    constructor(ctx: Context) : super(ctx)
    constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(ctx, attrs)

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        if (widthMeasureSpec < heightMeasureSpec)
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)
        else
            super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int size;
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthSize > 0) {
            size = widthSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightSize > 0) {
            size = heightSize;
        } else {
            size = widthSize < heightSize ? widthSize : heightSize;
        }

        int finalMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(finalMeasureSpec, finalMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                          <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />


                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.LinearLayout

class SquareLayout : LinearLayout {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val size = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size)
    }
}
```