# scaleType = centerCrop dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, crop

I have a gallery in my app. My photos are from the internet, so they are added dynamically. My gallery doesn't crop them to all be a perfect square. I would like to do this just to make my gallery look better. I tried this in my XML;

```
 ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

But because I am adding the image dynamically and not from `src` in xml, this wont work. Anyone know how to do this another way? I cant find anything on how to do it when added dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to scale the images dynamically you can use scaled bitmap method of bitmap to specifying size of your scaled down/up image programaticaly. Something like this:

Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, true);

For scaling details you can follow below link:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Comment: This distorts the image, not exactly what I wanted but it will do.

Answer (score 3):

If i am not getting it wrong we can do it with

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you laying the images out in a `GridView`? If so then the following will work. (If not, something similar might work but not tested by me).

Firstly it is actually a bit tricky to force a view to be *square*, as the width and height are measured separately. You can refer to [Simple way to do dynamic but square layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981029/simple-way-to-do-dynamic-but-square-layout) for some ideas. The simplest one (I think) is to create a new view inheriting from `ImageView` but overriding `onMeasure()`, e.g.

```
public class SquareImageView {

    // add usual constructors here

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // this will change the height to match the measured width
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Then change your layout xml to create instances of `SquareImageView` instead of `ImageView`. I think the rest of your attributes are OK, in particular `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` will ensure the image fills up the whole square.

After this, you download your image from whatever source into a `Bitmap` instance, then call `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` to display the image cropped to a perfect square. And that's it!