# Preview size wtith CWAC-Camera

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I've been fighting for a while with https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Managed to create my custom `CameraFragment` and a custom custom `CameraHost`.

I've overrode `getPictureSize` and `getPreviewSize`. With those two methods I'm able to find out which `Size`*s* are able to be used. My overall idea is to capture a square image, and also preview it before capturing.

I've been testing and no device is returning a square-formatted `Size`, so I guess the best approach would be taking the Size nearest to my needs. Like if I need an 800x800 squared image, I will return the nearest `Size`, that would be (for example) 1280x1024

So far so good. The issue is the following:

Documentation states:

> Usually, your CameraHost will be called with getPreviewSize()

Damn; my Nexus5 device never triggers this method, but a Genymotion emulator does. So in my emulator I can create a custom preview size, which I can't with my real device.
So I need some help with this issue. Why is it just "usually"? What can I do to change it to "always"?

On a second term, I need some tips: If I want an squared preview size, which I know it won't be available by default `Size`*s* returned by `getSupportedPreviewSizes`, what can I do to display an square? Maybe overlaying a square on top of `CameraFragment`? Is it even possible? Or should I go for any other approach?

Anyways, congratulations on the library; it's absolutely clear and with so many options. No need to worry about "some devices". That's great as an Android Developer.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I am on holiday/vacation right now. I'll try to help more next week upon my return.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thought so. Enjoy them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it just "usually"? What can I do to change it to "always"?

Quoting the documentation:

> If `getRecordingHint()` returns `ANY` or `VIDEO_ONLY`, though, `CameraHost` supplies the preview size via `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()` instead of `getPreviewSize()`. If you wish to use a different preview size for video, return it, otherwise return `null` and we will use the results from `getPreviewSize()` instead.

On API Level 11+, the implementation of `SimpleCameraHost` `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()` delegates to the `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()` implementation on `Camera.Parameters`, except for devices known to return poor values for it.

> what can I do to display an square? Maybe overlaying a square on top of CameraFragment?

I would try putting `CameraView` directly in your own UI, then layering something on top of it, using a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to control the Z-axis ordering.

Comment: To get a square preview do the following: Create your own activity and inflate the CameraFragment and add it to the activity as shown in this example http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/14/cwac-camera-an-easier-way-to-take-photos-in-android/ . Replace the FrameLayout that R.id.container refers to with a custom square FrameLayout which you implement like thus http://stackoverflow.com/a/10157573/1666063 - now you've got a square preview.

Comment: Yes, to get a square, must use other layout to cover up the unwanted area as @espen-riskedal said.  Also notice that, preview size must have exact ratio as one of those from the parameters list.  Otherwise, your preview will be stretched .  Picture size must have exact ratio you picked in preview size.  Otherwise, you output picture might look different than your preview screen.