# How to have equal size of width and height [square shape] using layout_weight?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I have following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test 2"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

that results:

[image]

How can I have equal size of View's height with its width (that is resulted by `layout_weight`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to override the onMeasure method  set the same height as the height. Please see this question: [Simple way to do dynamic but square layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981029/simple-way-to-do-dynamic-but-square-layout)

This is the complete solution that I come up with:

SquareLinearLayout.java :

```
public class SquareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthDesc = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightDesc = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = 0;
    if (widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
            && heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        size = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.default_size); // Use your own default size, for example 125dp
    } else if ((widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            && !(widthDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightDesc == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)) {
        //Only one of the dimensions has been specified so we choose the dimension that has a value (in the case of unspecified, the value assigned is 0)
        size = width > height ? width : height;
    } else {
        //In all other cases both dimensions have been specified so we choose the smaller of the two
        size = width > height ? height : width;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
 }
}
```

activity_my.xml :

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:listitem="@layout/item"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

</ListView>
```

item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.appsrise.squarelinearlayout.SquareLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test 1"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </com.appsrise.squarelinearlayout.SquareLinearLayout>

        <com.appsrise.squarelinearlayout.SquareLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test 2"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </com.appsrise.squarelinearlayout.SquareLinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return convertView;
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually my question is for listview item and I never try OnMeasure for listview item, but I think I should try it.

Comment: Hi Edy, I tried for OnMeasure but I am not sure why it doesn't work. After I tried code from your link, I use `ViewTreeObserver` and `OnPreDrawListener` but it gives me 0 for both width and height. I have found other solution that works.

Comment: Please present your solution then, as it might help others too.

Comment: Ok, I'll try later to implement the solution that I proposed, and if I succeed then we should compare the performances.

Comment: Sorry I think my solution is wrong, since when I tried to use margin, the View becomes rectangle, not square. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Your solution works great! However, previously I tried to use by extending TextView but it gives me undefinite height, but when in LinearLayout, it works.. Btw, would you please mind explain a bit why we need to declare default size first?

Comment: You could simplify the else if portion of your statement using a bitwise XOR operator ^, otherwise great solution and I thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler solution is to pass the width measurement specification into the height specification when calling `onMeasure` (or the other way around if you want the height to determine the square size).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SquareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{
    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        // or super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin version

```
[Register("SquareFrameLayout")]
public class SquareFrameLayout : LinearLayout
{
    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        var width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        var height = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        var widthDesc = MeasureSpec.GetMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        var heightDesc = MeasureSpec.GetMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && heightDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            //size = Context.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.default_size); // Use your own default size, for example 125dp
            height = width = 0;
        }
        else if(heightDesc != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && widthDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            width = height;
        }
        else if (widthDesc != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && heightDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            height = width;
        }
        else
        {
            //In all other cases both dimensions have been specified so we choose the smaller of the two
            var size = width > height ? height : width;
            width = height = size;
        }

        SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

and

```
[Register("SquareLinearLayout")]
public class SquareLinearLayout : LinearLayout
{
    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        var width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        var height = MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        var widthDesc = MeasureSpec.GetMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        var heightDesc = MeasureSpec.GetMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && heightDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            //size = Context.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.default_size); // Use your own default size, for example 125dp
            height = width = 0;
        }
        else if(heightDesc != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && widthDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            width = height;
        }
        else if (widthDesc != MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified && heightDesc == MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified)
        {
            height = width;
        }
        else
        {
            //In all other cases both dimensions have been specified so we choose the smaller of the two
            var size = width > height ? height : width;
            width = height = size;
        }

        SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also, If you need only one TextView needs to be square :

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textview.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    textview.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    int width = textview.getMeasuredWidth();
                    int height = textview.getMeasuredHeight();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textview.getLayoutParams();
                    if (width > height)
                        params.height = width;
                    else
                        params.width = height;
                    textview.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can divide a `LinearLayout` into two equal `LinearLayout` like this..

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

      <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Test 1"
             android:textSize="24sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

       <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Test 1"
             android:textSize="24sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will divide the `LinearLayout` into two equal `LinearLayouts` and each of these `LinearLayouts` will contain the `TextView`s

Comment: I think this one will make equally divided LinearLayout vertically, while what I want is height is same as the width resulted from layout_weight horizontally.

Comment: oops sorry..I've changed it to horizontal.But, what is your question actually?? you want height to be equal to width???

Comment: Yes, to be precise, I want square shape :)

Comment: try changing the height and width of `TextView` to `fill_parent`. But i dont think it will be square..

Comment: Yes, it will take whole screen height instead.

Comment: i would suggest you to divide the layouts until you get a square shaped layout and then you insert the `TextView`s in that square shaped layouts..Not sure if this is the right solution..

Comment: The issue here is that you're adding more views in the View hierarchy and that causes overdraw issues, which can be a performance problem.  I think the earlier answers using onMeasure() are better for that reason.