# Making width and height of children same in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to display three icons/images in a row. All the three must be square with same dimensions and they should fit in the screen. For eg:

```
+----------------------+
| +----+ +----+ +----+ |
| |    | |    | |    | |
| +----+ +----+ +----+ |
+----------------------+

+----------------------------------------+
| +----------+ +----------+ +----------+ |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| |          | |          | |          | |
| +----------+ +----------+ +----------+ |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I tried using LinearLayout with weights but it does not increase the height for larger screens. RelativeLayout also does not give any success.

Is it possible to do with XML Layout? If yes how to do it, if no then please give some pointers on how to achieve it pragmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981029/simple-way-to-do-dynamic-but-square-layout

Comment: @karaokyo Thanks for the pointer. I will check that out.

Comment: @karaokyo It worked for me. Thanks a lot.