# Is it possible to set the dimension ratio of a ConstraintLayout itself?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

> Not its separate components, but the dimension ratio of the `ConstraintLayout` **itself**, or **a group of elements together**.

I'm fallowing [this excellent tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/4071001) to build a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and two `CardView` columns that span the entire width of their container, each `CardView` (square) contains an `ImageView` (also square) and a `TextView`.

So, I need the `CardView` width to be "match parent" and get the same height (to be square), and the same goes for the `ImageView`. Something like this:

[image]

But this is what I have so far (note that `CardView` are not square):

[image]

This is my item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I know about `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`, but this is for use on any element within a `ConstraintLayout`, for example on my `ImageView`, not on `ConstraintLayout` itself.

I think I can invert my layout, put the `CardView` inside the `ConstraintLayout` and apply the above property to the `CardView`, but then I'm going to need another `ConstraintLayout` inside the `CardView` to place the `ImageView` and `TextView` properly, and I think it's not a good idea to nest `ConstraintLayout`.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3):

Try the item layout below. I have constraints the `ImageView` relative to `TextView`. It should work. Or maybe you have to add some margin to `ImageView`. Give it a try.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:text="Hello world"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but this is exactly my idea at the end of the question: _"I think I can invert my layout, put the `CardView` inside the `ConstraintLayout` and apply the above property (`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`) to the `CardView` (...)"_. So, the question here would be if it is correct to do it this way (nesting one `ConstraintLayout` within another), or as I believe, we would be negating the `ConstraintLayout`'s purpose of keeping a flat layout.

Comment: yeah but in this case nesting is required. because Root layout is dynamic . have a look at [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981029/simple-way-to-do-dynamic-but-square-layout) . You will find similar answers ..